# How to authenticate keycloak user in java

Tags: java, android, keycloak

Can anyone tell me how to authenticate keycloak user in android.
Using my login page in android, I have to authenticate keycloak user.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hello, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the available OAuth2.0 libraries such as [AeroGear](https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-android-authz), [Heimdall.droid](https://github.com/trivago/Heimdall.droid), etc.

Or write everything from scratch like I did [here](https://github.com/maslick/keycloak-android-native).

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to make API calls with some libraries, such as Retrofit2.

@Post localhost:8080/auth/realms/Realmname/protocol/openid-connect/token

with body as x-www-form-urlencoded
client_id
grant_type
client_secret
scope
username
password

In my video on youtube I created keycloak auth for android. But in java so for any java backend it would be the same.
https://youtu.be/DBf-XwYnRD8